# Python how do I overlay random images over images being generated to end up with 2 images with text

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Here is my code that I have so far. What it does is grabs a random text line from the text file an generates a random color then creates the JPG image with the text on top. What I want to do is take a random picture and overlay it on top of the solid color at opacity of maybe 0.2 or something then put the text on top of that so I end up with > solid color > picture overlayed > text on top. This code generates multiple images. It would be nice to have the text centered vertically also, but I'm not clear on how to do that.

```
import Image, random, textwrap, ImageFont, ImageDraw, os, sys
basepath = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]) + "/"

for n in xrange(10):

    keywordlist = []
    imglist = []
    keyword = file(basepath + "text.txt", "r")

    for line in keyword:
        keywordlist.append(line.replace("\n", ""))

        def type(name):
            value = name[random.randint(0,len(name)-1)]
            return value

    def random_color():
        return (random.randint(0,155), random.randint(0,155), random.randint(0,155))

    astr = ('%s' %(type(keywordlist)))
    para = textwrap.wrap(astr,width=19)

    MAX_W,MAX_H=640,400
    im = Image.new('RGB', (MAX_W, MAX_H), (random_color()))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    font = ImageFont.truetype('C:/windows/fonts/Arialbd.ttf', 58)

    current_h=0
    for line in para:
        w,h=draw.textsize(line, font=font)
        draw.text(((MAX_W-w)/2, current_h), line, font=font,)
        current_h+=h

    im.save('img%000d.jpg' % n)
```

Here is a sample of the output:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Use [the `blend` function](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm#image-blend-function):

```
new_image = Image.blend(solid_color_image, picture, 0.2)
```

Comment: So far I'm able to generate random colors an overlays, but the text is not appearing on the image.

Comment: @user1953451: You'll want to blend it right after you create the solid-color image and before you create the `ImageDraw.Draw` object.

Comment: I added the image.blend to the code below an it will generate an image with text, but no image, overlay and text.

MAX_W,MAX_H=640,400
im = Image.new('RGB', (MAX_W, MAX_H), (random_color()))
new_image = Image.blend(im, picture, 0.2)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
font = ImageFont.truetype('C:/windows/fonts/Arialbd.ttf', 58)

Comment: `new_image` contains the result, but you're not using it. You may want to use `im = ` rather than `new_image = `.

Comment: PERFECT!! that worked. It will now generate the solid color, overlay image and text on top of it. Do you know how I would 'vertically' center the text?

Comment: You know how many lines there are and how tall each line is. From that, you can figure out how tall the text will be in total. You also know how tall the image is. Then you know how much space is left. Centering vertically is just distributing that space above and below, so just divide the extra space by two and put that much extra space above.